# How to migrate websites and FTP sites from IIS 6 to IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net, iis, ftp, migration

I just got a requirement to migrate all of my websites and FTP sites to a new IIS 8 from existing IIS 6 server. With out installing any tool, how can we achieve this? If we manually do copy paste of all files, what are the configuration and authentication changes? Please let me know!!!

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

From Microsoft TechNet article, [Migrating a Web Server from IIS 6.0 to IIS 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ff633422%28v=ws.10%29):

> You can use the Web Deployment Tool (Web Deploy) to migrate your Web
> server or Web site from a computer that is running Information
> Services (IIS) version 6.0 on Microsoft® Windows Server™ 2003 to a
> computer that is running IIS 7.0 on Windows Server 2008 or IIS 7.5 on
> Windows Server 2008 R2. (In this documentation, "IIS 7" refers to both
> IIS 7.0 and IIS 7.5.) You can also use Web Deploy to migrate from an
> IIS 6.0 Web server to another IIS 6.0 Web server, or from an IIS 7 Web
> server to another IIS 7 Web server.

There is also a chapter on the IIS site "[Migrate a Web Site from IIS 6.0 to IIS 7 or above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/migrate-a-web-site-from-iis-60-to-iis-7-or-above)" which describes how to use the Web Deploy (msdeploy) tool.